# SQL Agent Job runs OK on 2014, but not 2017

Tags: sql-server, database

I just upgraded from SQL Server 2014 to 2017.  1 agent job that was running fine on 2014 is now throwing "failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259 error 22050".

I've made sure that the user that runs the SQL Agent service has sysadmin role, is a user in the database I'm reading and has datareader permissions on that database, but I'm still getting the error.

Additionally - the job history doesn't reflect the SQL Agent service user, but a computer account (that's not a login, by the way).  I have read that even though the job history reflects the computer account, it's probably being run by the user that's running the agent service.

I am at a loss.  I'm obviously missing some permission somewhere, but I don't know where.

Can anyone give me some guidance on this, please?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Did you upgrade in place? DId you also upgrade the client tools (e.g. sqlcmd)? DOes the command in the job step just say `sqlcmd.exe ...`? If so did you try an explicit path directly to the new or old version?

Comment: What is the actual job? Suspecting use of DBMail here, but we don't know without seeing your code

Comment: Thanks for the replies!!  It's a new server - so all new installation including tools.  The job is selecting data then emailing.  When I change the code to simply send a test email to myself it works fine.  It dies when I add in the query to select the data.  I've changed the job owner to sa, I've made sure that my login/user has datareader on the db and I've also given myself the database mail role, then set the just to run as my login, but still get an error.  I thought maybe it was the import, so I re-created the job from scratch, but still get an error.

Comment: I should have said the job is selecting data then emailing it as a .csv attachment. Sorry.